# PHP Array work homework

Tags: php, arrays

I have a homework for school in PHP arrays and there are some problem. I writing a torrent file info checker.

My code: `echo var_dump( $torrent->content() );`

And the output: `array(1) { ["Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.4 (15E65) Installer/Install OS X El Capitan.app.zip"]=> int(6205991074) }`

How can I make this to list:

```
Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.4 (15E65) Installer/Install OS X El Capitan.app.zip
<br>And More files...
```

And an other listing what listing statistics:
My code: `echo var_dump( $torrent->scrape() );`

And the output:

```
array(1) { ["Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.4 (15E65) Installer/Install OS X El Capitan.app.zip"]=> int(6205991074) } 
stats: array(1) { ["http://109.235.50.166:2710/scrape"]=> array(3) { ["complete"]=> int(98) ["downloaded"]=> int(11441) ["incomplete"]=> int(27) } }
```

How can I order to:

```
Downloaded: 11441
Downloading: 27
```

Thank you mates!

Comment: Well, it is a *homework* after all. You should do more research on your own first and ask what you must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like this:-

```
List Of Files:-


foreach($torrent->content() as $key => $value){
   echo $key."<br/>";
}

Status:-

foreach($torrent->scrape() as $key => $value){
   echo "Downloaded:" $value['downloaded']."<br/>";
   echo "Downloading:" $value['incomplete']."<br/>";
}
```